# Can the scroll direction of the trackpad and the mouse/trackball be set differently in macOS?

Tags: macos, mouse, touchpad, scrolling, scroll-wheel

On my MacBook Pro, I want to scroll direction on the trackpad to natural (two fingers swiping up to scroll down) but have the scroll action on my Kensington trackball be "natural to me" which is backward when the macOS has the mouse set to natural mode.  Is there a way to set the scroll direction for a mouse/trackball differently from the built-in trackpad?

Comment: I'm clearly not alone on this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6931667

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181186/natural-scroll-direction-on-with-trackpad-off-with-mouse